# How to generate java entity by Graphql schema

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm a newcomer for graphql java client development. Recently I meet a problem that how to generate a java entity through the graphql schema definition. Since in my side, the schema is always changing by another side, so I want a method to generate the java entity class automatically instead of reading the schema manually then change the code. If there are any practices on such a requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into the following [maven plugin](https://github.com/kobylynskyi/graphql-java-codegen-maven-plugin). It would help you generate Java classes from your `.graphqls` files.

Assuming you have only one file defining your GraphQL model, named *myGraphqls*, I would use this plugin as follow:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.github.kobylynskyi</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <graphqlSchemaPaths>
                            <graphqlSchemaPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/graphql/myGraphqls.graphqls</graphqlSchemaPath>
                        </graphqlSchemaPaths>
                        <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql</outputDir>
                        <packageName>com.graphql.model</packageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After running maven, you would be able to find in the *generated-sources* folder, a folder named *graphql* with the classes generated under the package *com.graphql.model*.

Comment: hi ,thanks your information. I tried this plugin, but it will generate a bundles of spring boot dependencies, which will conflict my origin spring framework. Can this be solved?

Comment: Nice plugin, but too many dependencies if you just want to generate the POJOs.